# How can I send message to MSN contact using YAHOO IM SDK

Tags: c#, msn-messenger, yahoo-messenger

I am writing a IM client and am using YAHOO SDK ported to C#. I am able to send and receive message to and from yahoo contacts by calling a getContactList method in the sdk and just then just simply send message to that contact. However, the getContactList method cannot get MSN contacts so I cant send message to MSN contact like in Yahoo Messenger. Anyone knows how Yahoo Messenger send message to MSN contact and shed me some light on this. Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Messenger#Interoperability
- http://www.ymessengerblog.com/blog/2012/11/30/updates-to-yahoo-messenger-features/

> As of December 14, 2012, the interoperability between Yahoo! Messenger
>   and Windows Live Messenger will cease to exist. The Live Messenger
>   contacts will appear as greyed out and it will not be possible to send
>   instant messages to them.